# how to find OneNote Notebook object from driveItem with MS Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

When a OneNote Notebook is created in OneDrive, Microsoft shows a `DriveItem` with a package facet and `type` of `oneNote`.  This is exactly per documentation. The `driveItem` appears to be a link/reference to the actual Notebook - which is stored in a "hidden" folder.

There are also Graph APIs to get a list of all the user's OneNote Notebooks, and you can retrieve a specific Notebook by it's `id`. The Notebook's `id`, however, is not the same as it's `driveItem`.

Given a `driveItem` with a OneNote package facet, how do I get the `id` of the actual Notebook so I can retrieve it and its details?

I have investigated pretty-thoroughly using Graph Explorer without success. I can't believe it would be true, but are the Notebook "names" required to be unique?  This is the only property I can see (other than owner/user-permissions) that would correlate across the two objects.

Answer (score 3):

The Notebook `id` isn't surfaced through the `DriveItem` resource. They're returned by the API so it acuratly reflect the same files returned by the OneDrive UI but they're not meant to be interacted with directly. For working with Notebooks, you need to use the [Notes API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/integrate-with-onenote).

The [OneDrive Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/integrate-with-onenote) is a bit more direct on this topic:

> #### Working with OneNote Notebooks
>
> **Note**: Although OneDrive stores OneNote notebooks, you shouldn't use the OneDrive API to work with OneNote notebooks.

This doc set also includes a more complete description of the [Package resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/package?view=odsp-graph-online).

At the moment there isn't a simple method to uncover a Notebooks's `id` from it's corrisponsing `DriveItem`. There is one trick you can use, but fair warning, this is *not* a documented method.

1. Using Graph Explorer (without loging in), execute the following call:

   ```
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01BYE5RZ35EU76DRTYZ5DK5DATNBSRPLC7
   ```
2. Look at the `eTag` in the result:

   ```
   "eTag": "\"{E13F257D-78C6-46CF-AE8C-13686517AC5F},1\""
   ```
3. Now take a gander at the list of Notebooks using:

   ```
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks
   ```
4. The first Notebook returned has the following id:

   ```
   "id": "1-e13f257d-78c6-46cf-ae8c-13686517ac5f",
   ```
5. When you look at these side-by-side, you'll notice the Notebook's `id` contains the same data as the `eTag`, albeit in a slightly different order (`{digit}-{guid}`):

   ```
   "eTag": "\"{E13F257D-78C6-46CF-AE8C-13686517AC5F},1\""
   "id": "1-e13f257d-78c6-46cf-ae8c-13686517ac5f",
   ```

I've used this myself but I would be careful and make sure your code used more than just the `eTag`  (I looked at the `eTag`, the `owner`, and the `name` properties). It isn't "supported" so it's possible this could change so comparing multiple properties could prevent a mishap down the just.

Oh, and don't tell anyone. This is just between us. ;)

Comment: Thanks Marc. I am trying to "take to heart" not using the Graph DriveItem to work with the notebook, that's why I was asking how to discover the Notebook's ID so I could use the relevant Graph-Notes APIs.  The Notebooks are surfaced in Drive as DriveItems, so users expect to "see them" in the folders that they (think they) stored them in.  Your "formula" to translate the ID looks right to me, but those undocumented features are obviously risky.  Strange that they would show the DriveItem, tell us not to use it for access, then not give us a way to get the actual notebook.  Thanks again!

Comment: I expect this will eventually go away but I complete understand how frustraiting it is in the meantime. There are a couple of functional overlap issues like this in Graph. A lot of these come down to disperate product teams each prioretizing their backlogs differently.

Comment: looks like your "secret" came out and Microsoft changed it :-(
This is no longer working.

The guid contained in the eTag of a driveItem is no longer related to the id of a notebook.

Maybe this still works if the notbook is at version 1

Comment: Still works with my 2 tenants