# Microsoft Graph API: recent items - How to get onenote displayName instead of filename

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

My goal is to display the 6 most recent items in the current users OneDrive.

Using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent?top=6 gives me the correct documents.

Some of these documents are OneNote Items.

At [www.office.com](http://www.office.com) the OneNote Items are displayed with the Notebook's displayname.
In the API response only the filename is contained.

Testing this is Microsoft's example data here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Example response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/recent?top=6&expand=section&$skiptoken=s!Njs3NGI0MzJjYS1mNmIzLTQ5YmQtOWIxMC02OTIyNjRlMTI3YTI",
    "value": [
        ...
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
            "createdDateTime": "2017-08-07T16:08:45Z",
            "id": "01BYE5RZ2IKLBQXYXELFD23BMJIB545TH6",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-01-09T03:02:37Z",
            "name": "Fabrikam.one",
            "webUrl": "https://m365x214355-my.sharepoint.com/personal/meganb_m365x214355_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B0BC35248-E4E2-4759-AD85-89407BCECCFE%7D&file=Fabrikam.one&action=edit&mobileredirect=true&wdorigin=Sharepoint&DefaultItemOpen=1",
            "size": 55782,
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "displayName": "Megan Bowen"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "",
                    "displayName": "System Account"
                }
            },
            "file": {
                "mimeType": "application/msonenote"
            },
            "fileSystemInfo": {
                "createdDateTime": "2017-08-07T16:08:45Z",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-01-09T03:02:37Z"
            },
            "remoteItem": {
                "createdDateTime": "2017-08-07T16:08:45Z",
                "id": "01BYE5RZ2IKLBQXYXELFD23BMJIB545TH6",
                "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-01-09T03:02:37Z",
                "name": "Fabrikam.one",
                "size": 55782,
                "webDavUrl": "https://m365x214355-my.sharepoint.com/personal/meganb_m365x214355_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/Fabrikam.one",
                "webUrl": "https://m365x214355-my.sharepoint.com/personal/meganb_m365x214355_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B0BC35248-E4E2-4759-AD85-89407BCECCFE%7D&file=Fabrikam.one&action=edit&mobileredirect=true&wdorigin=Sharepoint&DefaultItemOpen=1",
                "createdBy": {
                    "user": {
                        "email": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
                        "displayName": "Megan Bowen"
                    }
                },
                "file": {
                    "mimeType": "application/msonenote"
                },
                "fileSystemInfo": {
                    "createdDateTime": "2017-08-07T16:08:45Z",
                    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-01-09T03:02:37Z"
                },
                "lastModifiedBy": {
                    "user": {
                        "email": "",
                        "displayName": "System Account"
                    }
                },
                "parentReference": {
                    "driveType": "business",
                    "driveId": "b!-RIj2DuyvEyV1T4NlOaMHk8XkS_I8MdFlUCq1BlcjgmhRfAj3-Z8RY2VpuvV_tpd",
                    "id": "01BYE5RZ56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ"
                },
                "shared": {
                    "scope": "users"
                },
                "sharepointIds": {
                    "listId": "23f045a1-e6df-457c-8d95-a6ebd5feda5d",
                    "listItemId": "36",
                    "listItemUniqueId": "0bc35248-e4e2-4759-ad85-89407bceccfe",
                    "siteId": "d82312f9-b23b-4cbc-95d5-3e0d94e68c1e",
                    "siteUrl": "https://m365x214355-my.sharepoint.com/personal/meganb_m365x214355_onmicrosoft_com",
                    "webId": "2f91174f-f0c8-45c7-9540-aad4195c8e09"
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the OneNote notebook's name from here?

The API provides a way to retrieve all notebooks like so:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks

However I do not see a connection between these responses.

Maybe relevant [how to find OneNote Notebook object from driveItem with MS Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596532/how-to-find-onenote-notebook-object-from-driveitem-with-ms-graph) - this shows a workaround. I am curious if there is a better solution.